# How to prevent shuffling effect on UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I feel like there is a tiny bug in the following code which makes collection view cells to appear first time as they are quickly shuffling and then coming to their place, which is not good.

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)cv cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    BookCell *cell = [cv dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"BookCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *coverName = [[_dataSource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"cover"];
    NSString *cover = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:coverName ofType:@"jpg" inDirectory:@"covers"];
    cell.coverImage.image = self.placeHolderImage;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        UIImage *coverImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:cover];

        CGSize imageSize = coverImage.size;
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageSize);
        [coverImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width, imageSize.height)];
        coverImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                cell.coverImage.image = coverImage;
        });
    });
    ...    
    return cell;
}
```

Update: if I place log inside `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` I see that each cell is updating twice, which is causing the shuffling effect. But each time for example cell 0 have different image. Not sure what is causing this.

```
index: 0, cover: <UIImage: 0x156988d0>
index: 1, cover: <UIImage: 0x155b48f0>
index: 3, cover: <UIImage: 0x156b0660>
index: 2, cover: <UIImage: 0x1569d5a0>
index: 4, cover: <UIImage: 0x155eca20>
index: 5, cover: <UIImage: 0x155dece0>
index: 7, cover: <UIImage: 0x155c7d90>
index: 6, cover: <UIImage: 0x155d5920>
index: 8, cover: <UIImage: 0x155c7dc0>
index: 9, cover: <UIImage: 0x155b6d80>
index: 0, cover: <UIImage: 0x155cf410>
index: 1, cover: <UIImage: 0x1569c9a0>
index: 2, cover: <UIImage: 0x15692ca0>
index: 3, cover: <UIImage: 0x1555b7c0>
index: 4, cover: <UIImage: 0x155c9c90>
index: 5, cover: <UIImage: 0x156baee0>
index: 9, cover: <UIImage: 0x155cdf50>
index: 7, cover: <UIImage: 0x155b4630>
index: 8, cover: <UIImage: 0x15684af0>
index: 6, cover: <UIImage: 0x155c7950>
```

Comment: I would like to emphasize that the shuffling only happens first time I laod view controller. Then if I scroll it, everything is smooth and clear.

Comment: Basically what is happening, for example first cell is first showing one image, then rapidly changing to correct image. Same for other cells. This is causing shuffling effect. But not sure how to overcome this.

Comment: There is `[self.collectionView reloadData]` in `viewDidAppear`, which is causing double cell query.

Answer (score 0):

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        BookCell *updateCell = (BookCell*)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if (updateCell)
        {
            cell.coverImage.image = coverImage;
        }
    });
```

There's no need for the recursive call here. The block can capture the value of `BookCell`, so you only need:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            cell.coverImage.image = coverImage;
    });
```

to set your generated image. This may be the source of your problem.

As a matter of style, you're doing WAY too much in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:`.  Do all of this in side your custom `BookCell` class for better separation of concerns.

Comment: `cell.coverImage.image = coverImage` didn't address the issue. I don't think the code is so complex to separate it. The code is only to overcome UIImageView lazy loading issue, to have smooth scrolling. Yes, I have smooth scrolling, but shuffling effect first time is terrible.

Comment: Will need to see more code, then. This method only creates individual cells, and has no responsibility for layout. The issue must be elsewhere

Comment: The only part dealing with cells is here. BookCell only has an outlet for image. Placeholder is pre-loaded. Data source is not changing.

Comment: Other than the unusual call I noted before, there's nothing else unusual here - the issue must be elsewhere. As you using UICollectionViewControllet? or an embedded UICollectionView? How is the view itself presented? Etc., etc. I would look at how the view itself is presented. That's the most likely place

Comment: `UICollectionViewController` and it's simply connected to tab item. I tried to put `[NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:2.5]` after `UIGraphicsEndImageContext()` to see how this shuffling effect is taking place, but after 2.5s the shuffling and recovering happening immediately.  I was expecting to see that shuffling process slowly.